# The PsiLambdaExpression in the IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

Is there a ready-made solution (utility) to get the lambda interface (Function, Predicate, Supplier, Consumer, etc.) from PsiLambdaExpression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
import com.intellij.psi.LambdaUtil;

PsiType functionalInterfaceType = LambdaUtil.getFunctionalInterfaceType(expression, true); // expression: Map<Object, Object> map -> map.get(1)
functionalInterfaceType.getCanonicalText(); // java.util.function.Function<? super java.util.HashMap<java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object>,?>
```

or

```java
expression.getFunctionalInterfaceType();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this seem to be what you want?

```
import com.intellij.psi.*;
...
PsiType type = PsiFunctionalExpression.getFunctionalInterfaceType;
if (type instanceof PsiClassType) {
  PsiClass lambaInterface = ((PsiClassType)type).resolve();
}
```